# My function changes variable that is not in parameter

Tags: c, linux, memory, stack

I'm trying to make shell program that gets command based on linux and execute it in forked child processes. Now I'm trying to make

```
command < filename1 > filename2
```

where command gets input from `filename1` and sends output to `filename2`.

My first sample command was

```
sort < t > out
```

where "t" is `filename1`, "out" is `filename2`.

I needed to split the string `"sort < t > out"` to command part and file parts so I used 2 functions I made to split it.

First, I split `"sort < t > out"` into  `"sort"` and `"t > out"`. Then, I split `"t > out"` to `"t"` and `"out"`.

These tasks are performed by 2 functions: `make_tokens3` and `make_tokens4`.

However, when I try to split `"t > out"`, the value of `"sort"` that has been split in a previous function changes to a random string.

I tried to change memory amount I gave in `make_tokens4`, and each time I make other variables amount, memory that had `"sort"` changes like I said above. I can't reduce memory for variables anymore so I need help to manage memory. I think `strcpy` can be a problem, but I think I gave enough memory for variables

Edited to add code that you can run. If you run it, you can use commands like: ls, echo, cat... with '<', '>', '>>' redirection. But 'command < file > file' redirection is malfunctioning

After I posted this question, I found that my >,<,>> has also problem with memory and it is file name this time. It was OK with short name like "t" or "out" but when it becomes "out.txt" they read it like "out.txl".

```
#define MAXARGS   128
#define MAXLINE   256
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* function prototypes */
void eval(char* cmdline);
int parseline(char* buf, char** argv);
void make_tokens2(char* cmd, char* arg[], char* arg2[], char* target);
void make_tokens3(char* cmd, char* arg[], char* arg2, char* target);
void make_tokens4(char* cmd, char arg[], char arg2[], char* target);

int main()
{
    char cmdline[MAXLINE]; /* Command line */
    char* ret;
    while (1) {
        /* Read */
        printf("mini> ");
        ret = fgets(cmdline, MAXLINE, stdin);
        if (feof(stdin) || ret == NULL)
            exit(0);

        /* Evaluate */
        eval(cmdline);
    }
}

void eval(char* cmdline)
{
    char* argv[MAXARGS] = { NULL, }; /* Argument list execve() */
    char buf[MAXLINE] = "";   /* Holds modified command line */
    int bg;              /* Should the job run in bg or fg? */
    pid_t pid;           /* Process id */

    strcpy(buf, cmdline);
    bg = parseline(buf, argv);

    /* Ignore empty lines */
    if (argv[0] == NULL)
        return;

    /* Child runs user job */
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        setpgid(pid, 0);
        printf("parent1: %ld in %ld\n", (long)getpid(),(long)getpgid(pid));
        char* argf[MAXARGS] = { NULL, };

        if (strchr(buf, '<') != NULL) {
            //This is where the problem is
            if (strchr(buf, '>') != NULL) { //read from and write to file
                char* arg[MAXARGS]; char arg2[MAXLINE];
                char* arg3 = malloc(MAXARGS); char* arg4 = malloc(MAXARGS);
                make_tokens3(buf, arg, arg2, "<");

                printf("arg[0]: (%s)\n", arg[0]);
                printf("arg2: (%s)\n", arg2);

                make_tokens4(arg2, arg3, arg4, ">");

                printf("arg[0]: (%s)\n", arg[0]);
                if (arg[1] != NULL)
                    printf("arg[1]: %s\n", arg[1]);

                int fd1 = open(arg3, O_RDONLY, 00777);
                if (fd1 == -1) {
                    perror("mini");
                    close(fd1);
                    exit(1);
                }
                int fd2 = open(arg4, O_WRONLY, 00777);
                if (fd2 == -1) {
                    perror("mini");
                    close(fd2);
                    exit(1);
                }
                if (fd1 != -1 && fd2 != -1) {
                    printf("arg3: (%s), arg4: (%s)\n", arg3, arg4);
                    dup2(fd1, 0);
                    dup2(fd2, 1);
                    if (execvp(arg[0], arg) < 0) {
                        perror("execvp");
                    }
                }
                close(fd1);
                close(fd2);
                free(arg3);
                free(arg4);
            }
            else {                     //read from file
                char* arg[MAXARGS]; char* arg2[MAXARGS];
                make_tokens2(buf, arg, arg2, "<");
                int fd1 = open(arg2[0], O_RDONLY, 00777);
                if (fd1 == -1) {
                    perror("mini");
                    close(fd1);
                    exit(1);
                }
                else if (fd1 != -1) {
                    dup2(fd1, fileno(stdin));
                    execvp(arg[0], arg);
                }
                close(fd1);
            }
        }
        else if (strstr(buf, ">>") != NULL) {//this means to append to file
            char* arg[MAXARGS] = { NULL, }; char* arg2[MAXARGS] = { NULL, };
            make_tokens2(buf, arg, arg2, ">>");
            int fd1 = open(arg2[0], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 00777);
            if (fd1 == -1) {
                perror("mini");
                close(fd1);
                exit(1);
            }
            else if (fd1 != -1) {
                dup2(fd1, fileno(stdout));
                execvp(arg[0], arg);
            }
            close(fd1);
        }
        else if (strchr(buf, '>') != NULL) {//this means to overwrite file
            char* arg[MAXARGS] = { NULL, }; char* arg2[MAXARGS] = { NULL, };
            make_tokens2(buf, arg, arg2, ">");
            int fd1 = open(arg2[0], O_WRONLY, 00777);
            if (fd1 == -1) {
                perror("mini");
                close(fd1);
                exit(1);
            }
            else if (fd1 != -1) {
                dup2(fd1, fileno(stdout));
                execvp(arg[0], arg);
            }
            close(fd1);
        }
        else {                   //normal command with no redirection
            if (execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0) {
                perror("execvp");
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Command not found.\n", argv[0]);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        exit(0);//parent process exit
    }

    /* Parent waits for foreground job to terminate */
    if (!bg) {
        int status;
        pid_t waitstate = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        if (waitstate < 0)
            printf("waitfg: waitpid error");
        else if (waitstate >= 0)
            printf("wait for %d\n", pid);
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            int st = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("Exit status for child %ld: %d\n", (long)pid, st);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("%d %s", pid, cmdline);

}

int builtin_command(char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}

int parseline(char* buf, char** argv)
{
    int argc;            /* Number of args */
    int bg;              /* Background job? */
    char buf2[MAXLINE] = "";
    while (*buf && (*buf == ' '))
        buf++;
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = ' ';/* Replace trailing '\n' with space */
    strcpy(buf2, buf);

    /* Build the argv list */
    argc = 0;
    char* ptr = strtok(buf2, " ");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        argv[argc++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    argv[argc] = NULL;

    /* Ignore blank line */
    if (argc == 0)
        return 1;

    /* Should the job run in the background? */
    if ((bg = (*argv[argc - 1] == '&')) != 0)
        argv[--argc] = NULL;

    return bg;
}
/* $end parseline */

void make_tokens2(char* cmd, char* arg[], char* arg2[], char* target) {
    char* left = "", * right = "", * ptr = "";
    int num = 0;
    char cmd2[MAXLINE] = "";
    strcpy(cmd2, cmd);

    left = strtok(cmd2, target);
    strcat(left, "\0");
    right = strtok(NULL, target);
    strcat(right, "\0");

    ptr = strtok(left, " ");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        arg[num++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    arg[num] = NULL;

    num = 0;
    ptr = strtok(right, " ");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        arg2[num++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    arg2[num] = NULL;
    return;
}
void make_tokens3(char* cmd, char* arg[], char* arg2, char* target) {
    char* left = "", * right = "", * ptr = "";
    int num = 0;
    char cmd2[MAXLINE] = "";
    strcpy(cmd2, cmd);

    left = strtok(cmd2, target);
    strcat(left, "\0");
    right = strtok(NULL, target);
    strcat(right, "\0");

    ptr = strtok(left, " ");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        arg[num++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    arg[num] = NULL;

    strcpy(arg2, right);
    return;
}
void make_tokens4(char* cmd, char argc[], char argc2[], char* target) {
    char* left = malloc(MAXARGS), * right = malloc(MAXARGS);
    while (*cmd && (*cmd == ' '))
        cmd++;
    char* ptr = strtok(cmd, target);
    strncpy(left, ptr, sizeof(ptr));
    printf("left: (%s)\n", left);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, target);
    strncpy(right, ptr, sizeof(ptr));
    printf("right: (%s)\n", right);

    strncpy(argc, strtok(left, " "), sizeof(left) - 1);
    strncpy(argc2, strtok(right, " "), sizeof(right) - 1);
    free(left);
    free(right);
    return;
}
```

Comment: In order to compile your program we have to piece all those snippets together. Provide a single program instead.

Comment: Sorry my english isn't very good. Is this means that you need all of my code? It is one minishell.c and compiles with gcc -o and makefile. If you need it I can upload it

Comment: Your English is fine.  Please review [mre].  We would like a minimal program that demonstrate the issue.  Edit your question.

Comment: I get it now. Sorry in advance it will take a while

Comment: `char* ptr = strtok(cmd, target); strncpy(left, ptr, sizeof(ptr));`, and the similar calls with `right`: this will copy, at most, `sizeof (char *)` bytes. That is the size of a pointer, not the length of a string. `sizeof (char *)` is very likely to be just 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your system. `strncpy(argc, strtok(left, " "), sizeof(left) - 1);` has the same problem.

Comment: Note that `strncpy` has a [nasty side effect](https://man.openbsd.org/strncpy.3) of not null terminating the destination buffer if the length of the source string is greater than or equal to the size provided. Combined with using the size of pointers as copy lengths, this might explain why short filenames are fine but longer filenames display the wrong characters towards their ends. This is likely the effect of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) from reading uninitialized values, or past the end of a buffer that has not been null terminated properly.

Comment: Thank you. I have been working on it and I found that I was using the memory allocation in wrong way. I think I just have to learn more